# Writing the content of a csv-file into another csv-file

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem to write the content of a csv-file into another csv-file.

Fist I loop over several csv-files an write the lines in an array. At the end I'm looping through the array and write the lines in a new csv-file.

Here ist the structure of the original csv-files:

```
Dateiname;Name des Vorgängers;Schlagworte;Sujet;Name des Bildes;Alternativtext
s_m010_p001-001_01.jpg;;90039,90063,90068,60010,80000,80001,80008,90000,90055;Architekt, planen, beraten, Entwurfsplanung, gestalten, bauen, konstruieren, Gebäude, Firma, Unternehmen;s_m010_p001-001_01;
```

This is the structure of the array:

```
['s_m010_p001-001_01.jpg', '', '90039,90063,90068,60010,80000,80001,80008,90000,90055', 'Architekt, planen, beraten, Entwurfsplanung, gestalten, bauen, konstruieren, Gebäude, Firma, Unternehmen', 'abi_010_2015', '']
```

And here the result of the new csv-file:

```
Dateiname;Name des Vorgängers;Schlagworte;Sujet;Name des Bildes;Alternativtext
"s_m010_p001-001_01.jpg;;90039";90063;90068;60010;80000;80001;80008;90000;"90055;Architekt"; planen; beraten; Entwurfsplanung; gestalten; bauen; konstruieren; Gebäude; Firma;" Unternehmen;abi_010_2015;"
```

My code for reading the original csv:

```
with open(csvfile, newline="\n", encoding='utf-8') as aktuelleCSV:
    reader = csv.reader(aktuelleCSV, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter = ';', quotechar = ',')
    for row in reader:
        if reader.line_num !=1:
        csvArray.append(row)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The code for writing would be also interesting.

Comment: Could you explain what you are expecting and thus where the problem occurs, i.e. is the problem with the array (list) being created or is that correct but the file being output incorrectly

Comment: Giving an example does help, but you should also *specify* what you want

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. My error was in csv.writer. I used the wrong quotechar (',' instead of '"').

Thanks!